# CSS linear gradients rainbow wheel... not showing all 12 sections

Tags: html, css

I've nearly got this working, but am having an issue with displaying all 12 sections of the rainbow wheel.  I realise it will be something incredibly simple (Occam's razor).  I've followed this brilliant tutorial: [Dig deep into CSS linear gradients](https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/02/04/css-gradients/) but am falling at the last hurdle.

Here is a working Codepen: https://codepen.io/snarf1974/pen/aywZZJ

```
body { background: white; } 
.colorWheel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
/*   border: solid 2em white; */
  width: 16em; height: 16em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(30deg, #9bcb61 36.78%, transparent 36.78%),
    linear-gradient(60deg, #f6e04e 68.41%, transparent 68.41%),
    linear-gradient(-30deg, #f0463e 36.78%, transparent 36.78%) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(-60deg, #f57d42 68.41%, transparent 68.41%) 100% 0, 
    linear-gradient(-30deg, transparent 36.78%, #f9a260 36.78%) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(30deg, transparent 63.22%, #c14273 36.78%) 100% 100%,

    linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 31.59%, #86489b 31.59%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-30deg, #008fca 63.22%, transparent 63.22%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-60deg, #00bced 31.59%, transparent 31.59%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-30deg, transparent 63.22%, #82ba75 63.22%) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 31.59%, #00b8a9 31.59%) 0 100%,

    #f4c64d linear-gradient(#00bced, #00bced) 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.colorWheel:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -7em;
  width: 14em; height: 14em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  content: '';
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 22%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        padding: 1.5em;
        font-size: 1.4em;
      font-color: black;
      z-index: 1;
      -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
        transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only seeing 11 colours in your question: pink, yellow, cyan, orange, green, lawngreen, red, fuchsia, black, hotpink, purple.

I added this line before the lawngreen and it seems to work:

```
linear-gradient(30deg, transparent 63.61%, blue 31.59%) 100% 100%,
```

```css
body { background: white; } 

.colorWheel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  /* border: solid 2em white; */
  width: 16em; height: 16em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(30deg, #9bcb61 36.78%, transparent 36.78%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(60deg, #f6e04e 63.22%, transparent 63.22%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(90deg, #f4c64d 100%, transparent 100%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(-30deg, #f0463e 36.78%, transparent 36.78%) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(-60deg, #f57d42 63.22%, transparent 63.22%) 100% 0,
    
    linear-gradient(30deg, transparent 63.22%, #c14273 63.22%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 36.78%, #86489b 36.78%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0%, #008fca 0%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-30deg, transparent 63.22%, #82ba75 63.22%) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 36.78%, #00b8a9 36.78%) 0 100%,
    
    #f9a260 linear-gradient(#00bced, #00bced) 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}

.colorWheel:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -7em;
  width: 14em; height: 14em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  content: '';
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='colorWheel'>
  <div class='center'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much, I thought it would be something simple.  I've updated my codepen and the code above.  I'm trying to get all the sections to be equal using this: sin30°/(sqrt(2)*cos15°) = 0.3678 So the % value for the color stop is 36.78.  I've also done this for 60deg, but the sections still don't look equal.

Comment: Can anyone show me how split the sections in this rainbow wheel up equally? I've divided 360 / 12 = 30 and used sin30°/(sqrt(2)*cos15°), but it doesn't look right at all: [https://codepen.io/snarf1974/pen/aywZZJ]

Comment: @snarf1974 - Sorry I missed your first comment.  I have upated my code.  It was the `68.41` calculation that was off.  It should have been `63.22`, I believe

Comment: thank you so much for all your help, it works a treat!